# Submit data from drop down menu to mysql without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I am trying to find a way that I can submit data from a drop down menu to a php script without the page refreshing. At the moment, when the user clicks an option in the drop down menu, the form action is to send it to a php script which then runs the query to update the database. Here is the code for one of the drop down menus I am using. Any help would be amazing!

```
<form action="P1Append.php?PrimaryID=<?php echo $rows['PrimaryID']; ?>" method="post">
    <?php 
    $Check1=$rows['P1'];
    echo $check1;
    if($rows['PeriodInValue'] > '1' && $rows['Day'] == '1') {
    echo '<td bgcolor="#000000">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';  
    } else if ($rows['PeriodOutValue'] < '12' && $rows['Day'] == '2') { 
    echo '<td bgcolor="#000000">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';  
    } else if(empty($Check1)) {
                    echo '<td><b><select onchange="this.form.submit()" style=" width:30px; height:30px;font-size:12pt; background-color:white;" type="text" name="P1" id="P1" maxlength="15" size="1"><option disabled selected></option><option>G</option><option>R</option></td>';
                      }else if($rows['P1'] == 'G'){
                      echo '<td bgcolor="#02A10C">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';        
                      }else if($rows['P1'] == 'R'){
                      echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';
                      }else{

    }
    ?></form>
```

So I have been doing some searching on here, and i have found somebody else who has come up with a solution. I have implemented this into my code, but can't seem to get it working?? Any Help??

```
    <form onsubmit="return false">
        <?php 
        $Check1=$rows['P1'];
        echo $check1;
        if($rows['PeriodInValue'] > '1' && $rows['Day'] == '1') {
        echo '<td bgcolor="#0f5b92">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';  
        } else if ($rows['PeriodOutValue'] < '12' && $rows['Day'] == '2') { 
        echo '<td bgcolor="#0f5b92">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';  
        } else if(empty($Check1)) {
                        echo '<td><b><select style=" width:30px; height:30px;font-size:12pt; background-color:white;" type="text" name="P1" id="P1" maxlength="15" size="1"><option disabled selected></option><option>G</option><option>R</option></td>';
                          }else if($rows['P1'] == 'G'){
                          echo '<td bgcolor="#02A10C">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';        
                          }else if($rows['P1'] == 'R'){
                          echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $rows['P1'] . '</td>';
                          }else{

        }
        ?></form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //on the click of the submit button 
$("#P1").onchange(function(){
 //get the form values
 var P1 = $('#P1').val();

 //make the postdata
 var postData = 'P1='+P1+;

 //call your input.php script in the background, when it returns it will call the success function if the request was successful or the error one if there was an issue (like a 404, 500 or any other error status)
$.ajax({
    url : "P2Append.php?PrimaryID=<?php echo $rows['PrimaryID']; ?>",
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success: function(data,status, xhr)
    {
        //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
        $("#status_text").html(data);
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#brand').val('');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
    {
        //if fail show error and server status
        $("#status_text").html('there was an error ' + errorThrown + ' with status ' + textStatus);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Basically, you want to look into [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: I have had a look on here, and have seen a few tips, and i've been scratching my head for ages, just can't seem to get my head around it!!

Comment: It's a lot to absorb, to be sure. Many people use libraries to handle tasks like this. One of the most popular libraries is jQuery, which provides [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to make this as painless as possible. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/nq9hkvef/) is kind of what you're shooting for (obviously, this doesn't work and isn't complete, but hopefully it gets you started).

Comment: The best solution is to do a quick jQuery course: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/jquery it takes you step by step through the thinking and in an hour or two, you will be able to use ajax to code your form...

Answer (score 1):

You can make your life a lot easier by POSTing the data in JSON format.

```
$("#P1").onchange(function(){
//get the form values
var P1 = $('#P1').val();
var PrimaryID = <?php echo $rows['PrimaryID']; ?>;
//make the postdata
var postData = {
    P1: P1,
    PrimaryID: PrimaryID
}

 //call your input.php script in the background, when it returns it will call the success function if the request was successful or the error one if there was an issue (like a 404, 500 or any other error status)
$.ajax({
    url : "P2Append.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    success: function(data,status, xhr) {
    //if success then just output the text to the status div then clear the form inputs to prepare for new data
    $("#status_text").html(data);
    $('#name').val('');
    $('#brand').val('');
},
```

In your php script, you can simply grab the values via `$_POST["PrimaryID"]` and `$_POST["P1"]`

Comment: That makes sense. I have now updated my code to reflect this. When I click on the Drop Down It doesn't seem to do anything at all. It seems like it is not even attempting to run the Script??

Comment: try opening the developer console in your browser. You may have an error somewhere. If you are using chrome, you can open it with `ctrl + shift + i` then click `console`. also, check the `network` tab and look at the header of the request. you should see the form data that is being submitted there. also, check the preview and response tabs for the request to see what the server responded with.